# Struggling to Convert SQL Query to LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

How can I convert the below SQL query to LINQ.
I'm new in LINQ and I'm struggling to understand this

````
select d.[TerminalId],
       d.[NameLocation]
      ,d.[MachineType]
      ,d.[LastEvent]
      ,d.[LastRequest]
      ,d.[CurrentLoadset]
      ,d.[CanGetCash]
      ,d.[CanDeposit]
      ,d.[CanPrintStatement]
      ,d.[CanCheckBalance]
      ,d.[CurrentMode]
      ,d.[LastEventDetail] from Device d
  left join DeviceBranch db on d.TerminalId = db.TerminalId 
  where db.BranchCode = '2200'
  and db.TerminalId in (SELECT DISTINCT d.TerminalId FROM Device)```
````

Comment: What is your model and what have you tried so far with LINQ?

Comment: What's the aim in asking if Device.TerminalID is in (list of all TerminalId in Device)? I suspect this subquery does not do what you expect because it imports the outer query Terminal ID, meaning it ends up like `WHERE 1 IN (1)` for a terminalid of 1. Also, you mention a column in the where clause that has been left joined. This means the query will run as an inner join

Answer (score 1):

I believe the query has several issues and actually runs the same as this:

```
  select d.[TerminalId],
       d.[NameLocation]
      ,d.[MachineType]
      ,d.[LastEvent]
      ,d.[LastRequest]
      ,d.[CurrentLoadset]
      ,d.[CanGetCash]
      ,d.[CanDeposit]
      ,d.[CanPrintStatement]
      ,d.[CanCheckBalance]
      ,d.[CurrentMode]
      ,d.[LastEventDetail] 
  from Device d
  inner join DeviceBranch db on d.TerminalId = db.TerminalId 
  where db.BranchCode = '2200'
```

An LINQ terms this would be:

```
 from d in device
 join db in devicebranch on d.TerminalId equals db.TerminalId
 where db.BranchCode == "2200"
 select new {
   d.TerminalId,
   d.NameLocation,
   d.MachineType,
   d.LastEvent,
   d.LastRequest,
   d.CurrentLoadset,
   d.CanGetCash,
   d.CanDeposit,
   d.CanPrintStatement,
   d.CanCheckBalance,
   d.CurrentMode,
   d.LastEventDetail 
 }
```

you'll need to swap `device` and `devicebranch` for your client side collection names.

If you're doing this as part of a db context query that already has navigation properties set up you can look at skipping the join (let the ORM do it) and have something like:

```
//if a device has multiple branches
var x = dbContext.Devices.Where(d => d.DeviceBranches.Any(db => db.BranchCode == "2200"));

//if a device has a single branch
var x = dbContext.Devices.Where(d => d.DeviceBranch.BranchCode == "2200");

//starting from the branch table, branch has a single device
var x = dbContext.DeviceBranches.Where(db => db.BranchCode == "2200").Select(db => db.Device);

//starting from the branch table, branch has multiple devices
var x = dbContext.DeviceBranches.Where(db => db.BranchCode == "2200").SelectMany(db => db.Devices);
```

Comment: You could also say simply `select d` if you want to get the device object with all its properties. I put them all laid out like that because I couldnt tell if that was all the columns in the device table or not

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please

```
var result =
    (from d in Device 
    join db in DeviceBranch on d.TerminalId equals db.TerminalId into r
    from db in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where( db.BranchCode = "2200" && 
      (from de in Device select de.TerminalId).Distinct().Contains(d.TerminalId)
    )
    select d ).AsEnumerable();
```